# Adding variation on the fly and add to cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to change a product to variable, add a new variation, and add the product to the cart...this is what I have so far. I just want the cart to show the variable name...

```
//set the product to variable
wp_set_object_terms($product_id, 'variable', 'product_type');

//make a variation
$thedata = Array('_course_calendar'=>Array(
            'name'=>'_course_calendar',
            'value'=>'',
            'is_visible' => '1', 
            'is_variation' => '1',
            'is_taxonomy' => '1'
            ));


update_post_meta($product_id,'_product_attributes',$thedata);


//product_id,quantity,variation id,array
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($product_id,1,?,?);
```

The two question marks - the problem is how do I get the variation_id and what should I put in the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right so this was a bit more complex than I first thought..

A variation is like a product, it has a post and needs at least 3 parameters for meta, stock and price.

So here we go...

```
 //set the product to variable
 wp_set_object_terms($product_id, 'variable', 'product_type');

 //make an attribute and set it to variation, here the course calendar 
 //is simply the name of the var. What appears in the cart is the 'name' 
 //attribute so name it appropriately
 $thedata = Array('course_calendar'=>Array(
                'name'=>'details',
                'value'=>'',
                'is_visible' => '1', 
                'is_variation' => '1',
                'is_taxonomy' => '1'
                ));


 update_post_meta($product_id,'_product_attributes',$thedata);


 //check the variation  doesn't already exist if it does re-use it

 $result = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_parent =    $product_id", 'ARRAY_A');
        if($result)
            $id = $result["ID"];

//create the post variation if required

if(!$result)
{
   $post = array(
            'post_content'   => "", // The full text of the post.
            'post_name'      => "product-".$product_id."-variation", 
            'post_title'     => "variation added by <whatever> plugin", // The title of your post.
            'post_status'    => 'publish',  // Default 'draft'.
            'post_type'      => "product_variation", // Default 'post'.
            'post_author'    => 100, 
            'ping_status'    => 'open', 
            'post_parent'    => $product_id, // Sets the parent of the new post, if any. Default 0.
            'menu_order'     => 0, 
            'post_date'      => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
            'post_date_gmt'  => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
                );  
                $id = wp_insert_post($post);
 }

//set the stock/price meta, in my case a virtual product so no stock 
//req'd, the 4th true param ensures it is unique so only set once
add_post_meta($id, "_virtual", "yes", true);
add_post_meta($id, "_price", 0, true);

//finally insert your new product with the variation id and 
//a description which will appear in the cart etc...


$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($product_id,1,$id,Array('course_calendar'=>$product_desc));
```

Comment: Just a note to say I set the post meta price to 0 here, this obviously needs to be set to whatever the price should be